# What (and how) does Esterad Tissen know about Yennefer and Tannedd?

Tags: polish-language, the-witcher, andrzej-sapkowski

During Dijkstra's visit to Pont Vanis to see king Esterad, the former calls Yennefer a traitor, to which the king retorts that she's not, and that he can provide relevant proof.

*How* does king Esterad know Yennefer is not a traitor, and what kind of proof did he have?

Comment: Could you include the title of the book you're talking about?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, it could be _The Tower of the Swallow_.

Comment: Well, mentioning *anything*, like the book series or the author at least, might already help provide some context here.

Comment: @Cahir the series and the author are in the tags. I see no need to mention them elsewhere

Comment: I don't know, it helps form a coherent question that doesn't leave people confused about its context, like it did poor Lio for example.